# Receive compressed data using Boost::asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, compression

I have a client that sends me data using this function:

```
void CServerRetrieve::Send(char *buf, DWORD size, int flags)
{
    unsigned char *zlib;
    unsigned long szzlib;
    m_zlib.Deflate((unsigned char*)buf, size + 1, &zlib, &szzlib); // include the terminating 0 char
    char zbuf[5];
    zbuf[0] = 'Z';
    memcpy(&zbuf[1], &szzlib, 4);
    send(m_Socket, zbuf, 5, flags);
    send(m_Socket, (char*)zlib, szzlib, flags);
    delete [] zlib;
}
```

I want to receive this data using Boost::asio, however I am not sure what type of buffer I should pass to `socket.async_receive` in order for it to receive this data?

I have tried a `std::vector<char>` and `std::vector<std::string>`, however no data is ever received in my buffer?

Can someone assist me as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
void tcp_connection::start()
{
    socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buff), boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void tcp_connection::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!err || err ==  boost::asio::error::message_size)
    {
        size_t sz = buff.size(); //always 0!
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more code on this.. like binding your socket to an io_service and whether you have called io_service::run or io_service::run_one or not

Comment: I believe the compressed matter of the data has nothing to do with fact you don't  receive the data.

Comment: I believe you are getting some error_code in your handle_read function. Check what that error_code corresponds to. But again you should provide more of code atleast the ones where you are using asio features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are receiving compressed data really does not matter to Boost.Asio. Assuming you you know the size of the data you are about to receive, a `std::vector<char>` is fine for receiving the compressed data. You'll need to `resize` it prior to invoking `async_receive` Just make sure this buffer does not go out of scope until the completion handler is invoked. This concept is explained int the `async_read` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html).

> **buffers**
>
> One or more buffers into which the data will be read. The sum
>   of the buffer sizes indicates the
>   maximum number of bytes to read from
>   the stream. Although the buffers
>   object may be copied as necessary,
>   ownership of the underlying memory
>   blocks is retained by the caller,
>   **which must guarantee that they remain
>   valid until the handler is called**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming buff is your std::vector? In that case, before the async_receive you should probably initialize this with the size you intend to read, like

```
buff.resize(5);
```

You should also consider using async_read if you know the size of the message you're going to receive. In any case you need to set a size for your buffer.